# Unable to access String value from intent.getStringExtra MainActivity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

This my code, I want to send a String Value from this Activity to MainActivity by intent.putExtra,while accessing it in Main it gives no value.

```
package com.example.zccscores

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.RadioGroup
import com.example.zccscores.databinding.ActivityPlayerInputActivtyBinding

class PlayerInputActivty : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerInputActivtyBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPlayerInputActivtyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val dataOfTeam1 = intent.getStringExtra("team1Name")
        val dataOfTeam2 = intent.getStringExtra("team2Name")
        val team1Condition = intent.getStringExtra("team1Condition")
        val team2Condition = intent.getStringExtra("team2Condition")


        val selectedRadioButtonId = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.playerRadioGroup).checkedRadioButtonId
        val isplayer1Playing = selectedRadioButtonId == R.id.player1RadioBTN
        val isplayer2Playing = selectedRadioButtonId == R.id.player2RadioBTN



        binding.playerSaveBTN.setOnClickListener {
            val player1Name = binding.player1Name.text.toString()
            val player2Name = binding.player2Name.text.toString()



            if (player1Name.isNotBlank() || player2Name.isNotBlank()) {
                val player1Playing = "true"
                val player2Playing = "true"

                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("player1Name", player1Name)
                intent.putExtra("player2Name", player2Name)
                intent.putExtra("team1Name", dataOfTeam1)
                intent.putExtra("team2Name", dataOfTeam2)
                intent.putExtra("team1Condition", team1Condition)
                intent.putExtra("team2Condition", team2Condition)

                if (isplayer1Playing) {
                    intent.putExtra("player1Condition", player1Playing)
                }
                if (isplayer2Playing) {
                    intent.putExtra("player2Condition", player2Playing)
                }

                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                binding.player1Name.setError("Input required")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here i tried to pass the value

```
if (isplayer1Playing) {
                    intent.putExtra("player1Condition", player1Playing)
                }
                if (isplayer2Playing) {
                    intent.putExtra("player2Condition", player2Playing)
                }
```

While getting it here in MainActivtiy it gives no value

```
  val player1Condition = intent.getStringExtra("player1Condition")
        val player2Condition = intent.getStringExtra("player2Condition")

if (player1Condition == "true") {
            binding.batIcon1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 Condition true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (player2Condition == "true") {
            binding.batIcon2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Toast.makeText(this,"Player 2 Condition true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
```

I tried to Pass the Value from One Activty to another(MainActivity) using intent. I expected to visible my icon When the variable i am trying to get gives me a String value value "true". But it provides no value.It neither gives null value.I hope my question is clear and don't need much explanation.Please ignore the extra code.

Comment: You should simplify your code on SO as it gives a lot of unneccessary parts. And then you should try to debug for example what values are contained in the intent in MainActivity. When you check that and compare the code you will probably have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The intent code looks correct. You should try to debug using logging, to find out what exactly is going wrong. There are multiple conditional statements in your code so maybe you can output the values to see if those conditions are true. Here are few examples :

1. Output player names, to make sure the control is going inside `if` statement.

   ```
   binding.playerSaveBTN.setOnClickListener {
   val player1Name = binding.player1Name.text.toString()
   val player2Name = binding.player2Name.text.toString()
   Log.i("MainActivity", "Player1 name is $player1Name")
   Log.i("MainActivity", "Player2 name is $player2Name")
   if (player1Name.isNotBlank() || player2Name.isNotBlank()) {
                ...
   }
   ```
2. Output RadioButton checked state, to make sure you are actually putting in extras.

   ```
   Log.i("MainActivity", "Player1 radio button state is $isplayer1Playing")
   Log.i("MainActivity", "Player2 radio button state is $isplayer2Playing")

   if (isplayer1Playing) {
       intent.putExtra("player1Condition", player1Playing)
   }
   if (isplayer2Playing) {
       intent.putExtra("player2Condition", player2Playing)
   }
   ```

**Other tips:**

1. You can also use `boolean` data type in intent extras

   ```
   val player1Playing = true
   if (isplayer1Playing) {
       intent.putExtra("player1Condition", player1Playing)
   }

   // and get the data in second activity
   val player1Condition = intent.getBooleanExtra("player1Condition")
   ```
2. I would also advise to use Constants for naming IDs or keys. You can create a separate Kotlin file named Constants for storing all constants. This will help in preventing bugs where you set data with some key and try to get it with different key.

   ```
   // in a file named Constants.kt
   const val KEY_PLAYER_1_CONDITION = "player1"
   ```

   ```
   intent.putExtra(KEY_PLAYER_1_CONDITION, player1Playing)

   val player1Condition = intent.getBooleanExtra(KEY_PLAYER_1_CONDITION)
   ```